# Is it possible to write an update statement using replace where we just know the start and end of a string that we want to cut

Tags: informix

I have a table called `service` and a column called `xml`. In one of the records, the `xml` value is:-

```
select xml from service where xml like '%Password% ;
```

### xml

```
<UseUDS>true</UseUDS><UseUserCredential>true</UseUserCredential>**<DN>amrit</DN><Password>amrit</Password>**<SearchContext1></SearchContext1><SearchContext2></SearchContext2><SearchContext3></SearchContext3><RecursiveSearch1>true</RecursiveSearch1><SearchTimeout>5</SearchTimeout><BaseFilter></BaseFilter><PredictiveSearchFilter></PredictiveSearchFilter>
```

I want to write an update statement using replace function which should remove the `<DN>amrit</DN><Password>amrit</Password>` from the column value and keep the rest.

Please be informed that the string `amrit` can be anything.

I tried using wild characters but it didn't help — like below:-

```
update service set xml = REPLACE(xml,'<DN>%</DN><Password>%</Password>','')
where xml like '%Password% ;
```

Is it possible to write an UPDATE statement using REPLACE where we just know the start and end of a string that we want to cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you are working with a relatively newer version of Informix (like 11.70 or 12.10).
Here is one way to achieve what you are looking to do, provided your xml string is going to remain fairly straight forward as you've shown:
`update service set xml = concat(substring_index(xml, "<DN>", 1), substring_index(xml, "</Password>", -1)) where xml like '%Password%' ;`
Here is a complete list of string manipulation functions available in Informix https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1554.htm#ids_sqs_1554

Comment: Thank you so much Pradeep. Yes I use 11.70 . I totally forgot about concat and was banging my head around replace function.